# Custom Search Google API Download

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Google lists the binaries for the all their Google API's here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/Downloads

However when you download it and try to use the Google.Apis.Customsearch class it is missing.

It seems that the binaries at that URL are incomplete.

I don't understand this deployment methodology, the only way to get these libraries in their entirety is via NuGet from here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis/

Can someone please explain why the complete set of API's is not available at the first URL listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Downloads page you mentioned is for the client library itself (Google.Apis and Google.Apis.Auth assemblies for example). Each API (YouTube, Drive, Plus, etc.) is dependent on that library.

To download a specific API you should download it from NuGet, and it will download all the dependencies you need (like Newtonsoft.Json, Microrosft.Http.Client, Google.Apis, etc.).

So, if you want to work with Drive API for example, you should query the following: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=google.apis.drive&prerelease=true&sortOrder=relevance. Remember that the client library is beta, so you should "include "prerelease" in your search.